# Implementing Segment Routing Traffic Engineering (SR-TE) in IOS XR 6.3.1

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtualization, cisco, virtual-network, policy-routing

I'm trying to deploy `SR-TE` on `XRv9000` routers `IOS XR 6.3.1 version` which are deployed in *AWS* according to the topology below.

[image]

I have accomplished  the configuration of `SR` on all routers which is based on the official tutorial [Cisco's official SR tutorial](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/asr9000/software/asr9k-r6-3/segment-routing/configuration/guide/b-segment-routing-cg-asr9000-63x/b-segment-routing-cg-asr9000-63x_chapter_011.html). The following configuration is enabling `SR` on the routers.

```
router ospf 1
 distribute link-state
 router-id 1.1.1.1
 segment-routing mpls
 segment-routing forwarding mpls
 area 0
  interface Loopback0
   passive enable
   prefix-sid index 11
  !
  interface tunnel-ip0
   cost 1
   network point-to-point
  !
  interface tunnel-ip1
   cost 6
   network point-to-point
  !
 !
 mpls traffic-eng router-id Loopback0
!
```

As an instance, the *MPLS* forwarding table for *R1* is the following:

```
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:R1#sh mpls forwarding 
    Local  Outgoing    Prefix             Outgoing     Next Hop        Bytes       
    Label  Label       or ID              Interface                    Switched    
    ------ ----------- ------------------ ------------ --------------- ------------
    18022  Pop         SR Pfx (idx 22)    ti0          10.10.1.2       0           
    18033  18033       SR Pfx (idx 33)    ti0          10.10.1.2       0           
    18044  18044       SR Pfx (idx 44)    ti0          10.10.1.2       0           
    24000  Pop         SR Adj (idx 0)     ti0          10.10.1.2       0           
    24001  Pop         SR Adj (idx 0)     ti1          10.10.4.1       0
```

It looks like everything is set up Note, that each *MPLS* *forwarding table* shows only some difference of labels' order according to the adjacency's nodes. Moreover, I went forward for implementing which is presented here [SR-TE](http://www.segment-routing.net/tutorials/2017-03-06-segment-routing-traffic-engineering-srte/).

I would like that the traffic sent from source node `R1` to destination node `R3` by passing the following routers: `R1, R4, R1, R4` and `R3`. It may repass the same routers couple of times for reasons (*VNF order*). The path is given in the `segment-list` in the following `SR-TE` configuration for R1:

```
segment-routing
 global-block 18000 19999
 local-block 30000 30999
 traffic-eng
  segment-list name SIDLIST1
   index 10 mpls label 18011
   index 20 mpls label 18044
   index 30 mpls label 18011
   index 40 mpls label 18044
   index 50 mpls label 18033
  !
  policy POLICY1
   color 2 end-point ipv4 10.10.3.1
   candidate-paths
    preference 10
     explicit segment-list SIDLIST1
      weight 4
     !
    !
   !
  !
 !
!
```

For the Verification, the CLI `show segment-routing traffic-eng policy name POLICY1` can show if it is working.

```
RP/0/RP0/CPU0:R1#show segment-routing traffic-eng policy name POLICY1 
Thu Mar 28 11:15:58.799 UTC

SR-TE policy database
---------------------

Name: POLICY1 (Color: 2, End-point: 10.10.3.1)
  Status:
    Admin: up  Operational: down for 00:00:19 (since Mar 28 11:15:39.411)
  Candidate-paths:
    Preference 10:
      Explicit: segment-list SIDLIST1 (active)
        Weight: 4
          18011
          18044
          18011
          18044
          18033
  Attributes:
    Binding SID: 24003
      Allocation mode: dynamic
      State: awaiting operational
      Policy selected: no
    Forward Class: 0
```

It is obvious that it is not working, before hand I chose an explicit path not `dynamic` for `allocation mode`. and the `Operational` is `down`.
Something is missed, may I have help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MPLS data plane is not working at all in AWS IOS XRv instances on AWS.